# jquery, send a form by staying on the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want to send a form without leaving my current page, so I'm using:

```
$('.myForm').on('submit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(html) {
            alert('ok');
            }
        });
    return false; 
});
```

but it doesn't work... any idea please?

Comment: In what way, 'doesn't work'?

Comment: make sure your form has the class "myForm".

Comment: `return false` means `continue` in jQuery speak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
        alert('ok');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You need to actually pass in the `event` in the function.

Comment: This still takes me to a new page

Comment: @DanielCJacobs Your URL in action will not of the same page...

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
 <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
 <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

The jquery part

```
$("#update").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val(); 
  var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
  var dataString = 'name='+name+'&last_name='+last_name;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:'insert.php',
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The `insert.php` page

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $insert = "insert into TABLE_NAME values('$name','$last_name')";// Do Your Insert Query
  if(mysql_query($insert)) {
   echo "Success";
  } else {
   echo "Cannot Insert";
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i would choose this as the best answer, allthough i prefer the user feedback to come from the client (not php).

Answer (score 2):

use `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('.myForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
        alert('ok');
        }
    });
    //return false; 
});
```